# Why is OnAuthorization called twice in my custom AuthorizationFilterAttribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, authorization

Why is `OnAuthorization` called twice for my straight forward `AuthorizationFilterAttribute`?

```
public class ApiAuthenticateAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
   public void override OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if(NotAuthorized())
            throw new Exception();

    }
}
```

#### First Call Stack

[image: First Call Stack]

#### Second Call Stack

[image: Second Call Stack]

Comment: maybe because your request is cross origin

Comment: Can you check the call stack?

Comment: maybe its because you didn't override the base method?

Comment: Typo. Added `override`.

Comment: How are you making the request? There are plenty of reasons why this might happen. Soheil Gh already pointed one such reason in the first comment.

Comment: It's all localhost, I'm looking into this some more. This started happening when I added the attribute to the global filters in `WebApiConfig.cs`. Before then, it was decorated on the controller.

Comment: @Omar If you have put this actionfilter on controller and your action use some partial that is executed from your controller itself then your partial will also called the actionfilter again.

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta by `partial` do you mean partial views? This is an API project not an MVC one. No HTML rendering happens.

Comment: @SoheilGhahremani I'm getting the same issue, my request is cross origin but on most of my requests when I return Unauthorized it works fine.  But when I include the header `withCredentials` the Unauthorized is fired twice.  Do you know what that would be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with Ninject.Web.WebApi. For some reason it was registering the filter twice. Updating the package to latest (v 3.2.1) fixed the issue.

Comment: I have 3.2.4 installed but have the same problem, so I need to override AllowMultiple property this way: public override bool AllowMultiple { get { return false; } }

Comment: public override bool AllowMultiple { get { return false; } }  worked for me as I am not using ninject in my project

Answer (score 3):

I had registered the AuthorizeAttribute in the WebAPIconfig.cs:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
   config.Filters.Add(new Global.Security.MyAuthorizeAttribute());
```

In addition I had decorated the method with the Attribute.

```
[MyAuthorize]
public IHttpActionResult Get(string name)
```

This caused the `public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)` method to be called twice.

The solution is either set one up globally (as a config filter) or add attributes to methods individually.