# How to prevent custom filters twice calls?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I have a custom authorize filter that called two times.

```
public sealed class SamaAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        //some code
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        //some logic code here
        return true;
    }
}
```

I just add it globally and not set it for any action.
i search it in all web but can not find good answer.
i used StructureMap library for dependency injection;
but i don't have any ioc filter registration.
even i used "AllowMultiple = false" but not worked for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is OnAuthorization called twice in my custom AuthorizationFilterAttribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849343/why-is-onauthorization-called-twice-in-my-custom-authorizationfilterattribute)

Comment: thanks . i checked your link .i think second answer is not my answer . because i pointed to it in my question : i just register as global filter and not use filter for any controller or action. but first answer about ioc , i don't know to how solve it if ioc registration was problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was an ajax call in my scripts.